# Success response from FCM but no notification

Tags: javascript, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

On the client side I request for permission and send token to server

```
messaging.requestPermission()
.then(function() {
    console.log('Notification permission granted.');
    return messaging.getToken();
})
.then((token) => {
    if (token) {
        const body = JSON.stringify({
            token,
            stopId: 'BKK_F02550',
            routeId: 'BKK_0205',
        });
        const headers = {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        };
        console.log(token, 'token');
        fetch('/api/test', {method: 'post', body, headers});
    } else {
        console.log('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
    }
})
.catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
});
```

On the server side I send the request to FCM:

```
app.post('/api/test', (req, res) => {
    const body = {
        "to": req.body.token,
        "notification":{
            "title":"Portugal vs. Denmark",
            "body":"great match!"
        }
    }

    const headers = {
        Authorization: `key=${serverKey}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    fetch('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', body, headers)
        .then(data => res.status(200).json(data))
        .catch(error => console.log('failure', error))
})
```

I receive a success response but I don't get the notification on the client side. I feel like the gist of the response object is this: {size: 0, timeout: 0}.

Comment: From the server, what is the value of `req.body.token`? Can you log it?

Comment: yes, I've done that and I have the same token value on both sides

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think there is a sequential problem at your client side code. As returning with `return messaging.getToken()`; will never come over remaining codes that, you will see, I tried to reorganized below. (I am not sure for next problems but will check after).

```
messaging.requestPermission()
.then(function() {
    console.log('Notification permission granted.');
    .then((token) => {
          if (token) {
              const body = JSON.stringify({
                  token,
                  stopId: 'BKK_F02550',
                  routeId: 'BKK_0205',
              });
              const headers = {
                  'Accept': 'application/json',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              };
              console.log(token, 'token');
              fetch('/api/test', {method: 'post', body, headers});
          } else {
              console.log('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
          }
      })
   return messaging.getToken();
 })
.catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
});
```

Comment: I think that bit should be fine, I get a token back and it is passed to the server side.